# What CSS / JS tricks drive the mirror inverted http://com.google April fools page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Maybe you saw the hillarious https://com.google/ mirror inverted (and actually functional) version of Google.com. I just looked at its source briefly but couldn't quite figure out what the core programming tricks at play are that allow this to work.

The folks at Google seem to load the regular google.com page in an i-frame but then what? Can anyone explain how they pull this off?

Comment: As far as I understand it's simply a transformed element, removing the `transform: rotateY(180deg)` and the `transform: scaleX(-1)` returns it to normal.

Comment: CSS: `transform: scale(-1, 1);` or `transform: rotateY(180deg);`

Comment: The real trick is that they have their own TLD `.google`… :-\ Why not `.kfc` or `.pampers`?

Comment: @Gras Double - that cost them but obviously they have no clue what to do with it... "The evaluation fee is estimated at US$185,000" quoted from http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/customer-service/faqs/faqs-en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of two css rules:

```css
.text {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Reverse me</div>
```

UPD: Rules used for compatibility on the actual com.google page:

```
body {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Comment: Looking for that I found that they seem to use: body{-moz-transform:scaleX(-1);-o-transform:scaleX(-1);-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);transform:scaleX(-1);filter:FlipH;-ms-filter:"FlipH"}

Comment: @C.O. the vendor prefixes are included for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Uses a transform to make a mirror effect, in layout

the google uses

```
.mirror {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

but can be used too

```
.mirror {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```